# Change an integral value's data type while keeping it normalized to the maximum value of said data type in C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I want to change a value, of, let's say, type `int` to be of type `short`, and making the value itself be "normalized" to the maximum value `short` can store - that is, so `int.MaxValue` would convert into `short.MaxValue`, and vice versa.

Here's an example using floating-point math to demonstrate:

```cs
public static short Rescale(int value){
    float normalized = (float)value / int.MaxValue; // normalize the value to -1.0 to 1.0
    float rescaled = normalized * (float)(short.MaxValue);
    return (short)(rescaled);
}
```

While this works, it seems like using floating-point math is really inefficient, and can be improved, as we're dealing with binary data here. I tried using bit-shifting, but with to no avail.

Both signed and unsigned values are going to be processed - that isn't really an issue with the floating point solution, but when bit-shifting and doing other bit-manipulation, that makes things much more difficult.

This code will be used in quite a performance heavy context - it will be called 512 times every ~20 milliseconds, so performance is pretty important here.

How can I do this with bit-manipulation (or plain old integer algebra, if bit manipulation isn't necessary) and **avoid floating-point math** when we're operating on integer values?

Comment: @hijinxbassist I'm trying to solve this in the "right way", and not by creating a bunch of floats, as that's pretty expensive - I was thinking of using bit-manipulation. But I should've included that in the question, I'm a little sleepy, sorry :)

Comment: MAybe something like `return (value >= int.MaxValue) ? short.MaxValue : ((value <= int.MinValue) ? short.MinValue : Convert.ToInt16(value));`

Comment: For the performance part of the question. Just benchmark it.

Comment: @Ralf No, that won't work... that's not normalization. The only cases when that statement would work is when we would pass int.MaxValue or int.MinValue. Anything else, like `int.MaxValue - 1` would throw an OverflowException, i.e. `1073741823`, which should translate to `16383`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the shift operator. It is very fast.
int is 32bits, short is 16, so shift 16 bits right to scale your int to a short:

```
int x = 208908324 ;
//32 bits vs 16 bits.
short k = (short) (x >> 16);
```

Just reverse the process for scaling up.  Obviously the lower bits will be filled with zeros.

Comment: Would this work when converting a `int` to a `long`? I tested it with converting `long` to `int`, and it works, but while doing it the other way around, I'm getting some... "inaccuracies", you could say. Here's the code to show what I'm talking about: https://onlinegdb.com/B5lxaf0XM

Comment: @boooba that happens because `long.MaxValue / int.MaxValue` is not 2^32 (which the left-shift scales by) but approximately 2^32 + 2, you can compensate for that easily by also adding `2L * value` after the shift, but that only works properly for non-negative values.

Comment: @harold Oh, alright. After some testing, I've noticed that the inaccuracies aren't really a big problem for my algorithm, so I'll mark this answer as "accepted". Thanks!